# error while publishing asp.net web site on ftp server

Tags: .net, ftp

I was publishing an asp.net website on ftp server. During publishing the source code, I got the following thing in log,

Unable to add 'abc.aspx' to the Web site.  Can't connect to 'ftp://ftp.abc.com.np' on port 21. Check the server name and proxy settings. If the settings are correct, the server may be temporarily unavailable. This message is generated for every page that is being published.. This problem was not encountered earlier. However, as i enter the address on browser, the page is opened. Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you enter the address in the browser, make sure you use the full `ftp://ftp.abc.com.np` url so that it doesn't use http by accident.

Comment: i did it anders, this shows the files and folder. but my issue is during publishing of application on ftp server, not during viewing the site.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I just wanted to make sure that you didn't accidentally use `http` when testing in the browser.